# Insert a list item with html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unordered list, and I am trying to insert an element at the end

```
jQuery("<li>").text(" | Billed (14)").appendTo('.subsubsub')
```

However, I would like it to be formated with the following

```
 | <a href=''>Billed <span class='count'>(14)</span></a>
```

But when I do:

```
jQuery("<li>").text(" | <a href=''>Billed <span class='count'>(14)</span></a>").appendTo('.subsubsub')
```

It just prints the entities instead of parsing them.

Comment: Use `html` instead of `text`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use `.html()` to inject html.

```
jQuery("<li>").html(" | <a href=''>Billed <span class='count'>(14)</span></a>")
    .appendTo('.subsubsub')
```

Answer (score 0):

text() is not for HTML, it escapes any HTML characters, use html()